# Как локализовать время в Django?

Tags: python, django

Всем привет, я новичок.

В модели есть поле `DateTimeField`, когда вывожу его в шаблоне, выводится время создания записи по часовому поясу указанному в настройках. Как выводить время по часовому поясу клиента? В настройках `USE_TZ = TRUE`
Искал решение в интернете, не нашел.

Comment: Ну для начала откуда-то узнать, а какой часовой пояс у клиента вообще. А после этого https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone

Comment: Можно получать IP пользователя и по нему узнавать примерную локацию.